# Deploy AWS UserPool via CloudFormation with attribute update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

If you deploy a UserPool via CloudFormation, e.g:

```
Resources:
  UserPool:
    Type: 'AWS::Cognito::UserPool'
    Properties:
      ...
      Schema:
        - Name: email
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
```

and then update the attributes to make `name` required:

```
Schema:
  - Name: email
    AttributeDataType: String
    Mutable: true
    Required: true
  - Name: name
    AttributeDataType: String
    Mutable: true
    Required: true
```

AWS thinks that `name` is a custom attribute and fails with:

> Required custom attributes are not supported currently. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: ...)

It's only an update that fails, deploying a clean stack correctly sets both the `email` and `name` standard attributes to required.

Is there any way for the update to succeed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately this is some sort of bug from CloudFormation. Very similar to other issues, for example on the update of DynamoDB tables with more than one index.

The only feasible way to do the update is to do that in two steps:

1. Remove the attribute that has to be changed (in your case `name`), deploy the CloudFormation
2. Add the attribute with the correct values (so adding `Require: true` in your case), deploy the CloudFormation

As previously said there are quite a lot of issues similar to that case, and you'd better signal your issue to AWS in order to get support and the bug fixed.

Comment: Thanks, it seems in this case that standard attributes cannot be configured after first deployment of the stack, as any update results in a custom attribute of the same name, so those steps result in the same error.

Comment: DynamoDB GSI updating behavior is explained a bit here: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/229